# Fluid dynamics tsunami

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, water, tsunami

I have been given a energy head (pressure) in meters for a given tsunami on land. 
If the tsunami hits a wall 1 meter by 1 meter, is it possible to calculate the height it will reach.
I am thinking it is due to the fact that a liquid is incompressible and therefore a given pressure will make the tsunami height rise when it hits the wall to a certain height.

Comment: Making the impractical assuming no energy gets transferred to the wall, the entire energy will be converted to potential energy

Comment: so if you assume some energy is transferred to the wall can you calculate, how much energy would be transferred and/or the maximum height the column of water will reach?

Comment: What is the initial height of the tsunami wave? Why do you think water should increase in height when it hits the wall?

Answer (score -1):

a liquid is not perfectly incompressible - see cavitation in fluids.
still, i think we can assume that here .
we can calculate the maximum possible height reachable.
If i assume that the wall is perfectly rigid and it cannot move when the wave hits it, and if i also assume that the wave system is perfectly conservative , i.e: no energy is lost as heat or sound , then there should be no loss in total mechanical energy of the wave K + U . 
now as tpb261 said, the height reached will be maximum when the potential energy in maximum.
so , if we know hte approximate velocity of the waves and by choosing a suitable reference frame , we can calculate the maximum height reachable.

Comment: I'm not sure that cavitation is a good example to show that liquids aren't perfectly incompressible...